# How to Fix "Unable to load DLL 'webengine.dll'"

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008

Out of the blue today I started getting this error in Visual Studio 2008 when I go to compile a website, compiling a class library is no issue.  My project is based in ASP.NET 3.5 and another in 2.0

> Unable to load DLL 'webengine.dll':
>   The specified module could not be
>   found. (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x8007007E)

I've tried uninstalling, reinstall .NET versions, service packs, etc... nothing in my searches have helped me.

Comment: It might help to post what you have tried so far. For example, does this help: http://www.dotnetmonster.com/Uwe/Forum.aspx/dotnet-csharp/85099/Unable-to-load-DLL-webengine-dll

Comment: Well I posted this in a bit of a frustrated moment, but I covered the spirit of what you spoke of in my question.  I put this here hoping somebody knew the magic bullet, because searching wasn't helping!  I read the article you recommended several times...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well after a day of frustration I figured out how to recover from this error.  I have no idea why it happened, as I was fine at the end of the day yesterday and hosed at the beginning of the day today.

But I had to completely, and I stress completely, uninstall .NET.  The normal uninstall leaves remnants of the install.  However this page gives you a tool to completely uninstall .NET:

http://blogs.msdn.com/astebner/pages/8904493.aspx

After uninstalling .NET it will force you to reboot.  Then go into your windows\microsoft.net folder and delete (or rename) the framework folder.  Finally, re-install .NET and the error will hopefully be gone for you as well.

Answer (score 1):

For me a simple restart did the trick. I know that wasn't exactly your problem but maybe this helps someone else who came here via search engine...

Comment: Oddly enough experienced the same.  Restarting IIS had no effect yet restarting Windows fixed the issue.  Root cause unknown.