# aspnet_regiis.exe not working?. Where i find the Download link?

Tags: asp.net

[Temporary ASP.NET Files Missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9907837/temporary-asp-net-files-missing)

I struck with this error at yesterday itself. I googled for this. Somebudy told me to check, aspnet_regiis.exe working or not in this path.

file:///C:/windows/microsoft.net/framework/v2.0.50727/

Oh it not working. Warning is,...

```
The Program Can't start because webengine.dll is missing from your computer. try re installing the program to fix this problem.
```

Where can i find the download link.

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling, then re-installing .Net 2.0? According to [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2344238/how-to-fix-unable-to-load-dll-webengine-dll), you may also have to take some extra steps to make sure you cleanly uninstall it.

Comment: What Are the steps want to i do?. Please tell me. I am ready to do this.

Comment: The [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2008/08/28/8904493.aspx) here was the accepted answer from a similar question. Try following those directions.  You can also try to going to `Add/Remove Programs and Features` in your control panel to uninstall. Another option is to download .Net Framework from Shailesh's link and run it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download it from http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=19.

Answer (score 0):

You can download and re-install the .net framework 2.0. After this it will allow you to register the asp.net with IIS. Ensure the IIS is configured in your windows feature.